# SQL suma de totales sumados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera me ayudaran. Esta ves con una orientacion de suma de totales de otras sumas.

El error me indica que:

> La funcion `sum` requiere 1 argumento.

***Algo del codigo:***

```
select
    colum1 as Total,
    colum2 as Co,
    Sum (price) as [Total],
    Sum(Amount) as TotalMes,
    Sum (NatAmount) as PrecioNal,
    Sum (Price,Amount,NatAmount) as TotalCo
From
    Articulos,
    Tickets
Where
    fecha Between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
Group by
    Column1,
    Column2,
    Price,
    Amount,
    NatAmount
order by
    Total asc
```

Gracias.

Comment: sum recibe un solo parametro.. si queres la suma de mas de una columna, "sumalas internamente" = sum(col1+col2+col3+...etc)... y si no pones una clausula de join, va a joinear toda una tabla contra toda otra tabla..

Comment: Hola, ya lo intente y me sale que requiere un argumento, me sigirieron un procedimiento, que lo sume y luego lo sentencie al final de la consulta

Comment: como lo escribiste? sum solo recibe una columna.. si queres mandarle mas podes hacer lo que te dije o hacer sum(col1)+sum(col2)... etc

Comment: si, lo efectue asi : sum (sum colum1+ sum colum2+sum colum3) me indica aun que requiere un argumento

Comment: sigue estando mal. No leiste ni mi ejemplo ni la documentacion de sum no? es sum(columna1 + columna2+ etc...) no hay un sum adentro del sum. salvo que estes buscando hacer alguna otra cosa rara.

Comment: disculpa, pero tambien lo efectue asi, en este proceso de prueba y error

Comment: gracias, en este ultimo me solicita el argumento pero como vos me lo indicas, sale vacio el resultado

Comment: Por favor.. pone un ejemplo de tu s datos, de la salida que queres, y de los intentos que hiciste y los errores que recibiste.. tene en cuenta que ese from esta mal porque hace un cross join entre todas las filas!. mira por favor [ask] y tambien el [tour]

Comment: y no deberias agrupar por ,Price,Amount,NatAmount  si forman parte de la suma. Me parece que toda tu consulta esta mal y por eso estas recibiendo cualquier resultado. Por favor, aclara toda tu pregunta.

Comment: gracias,  por la aclaracion, aunque lo que quiero es que me salga la suma total de cada columna y luego la suma de estas creo que el query evidencia como quiero que salga....o sera por orden ? aunque creo que eso no tendria nada que ver igual seria bueno confirmarlo, de nuevo gracias

Comment: Entonces es la otra version, es sum(col1)+sum(col2). por eso te dije que arreglaras la pregunta, ya que realmente no se entiende que estas buscando. Puede que en tu cabeza este clarisimo, pero desde otro lado, no podemos saber que hay en ella.

Comment: de acuerdo, aunque tambien ya lo habia intentado asi....de todas formas gracias

Comment: Pero pudiste solucionarlo?

Comment: aun me arroja campos vacios...y es una macro, estoy indagando por si acaso, mil gracias¡

Comment: ese from no esta bien. y el group by tampoco. por eso los resultados raros

Comment: lo estoy revisando pero me pasa igual si solo selecciono una tabla y de acuerdo a las columnas de la misma tabla me arroje un resultado y sigue igual

Comment: no podremos ayudarte mucho mas sin ver los datos y el resultado esperado.

Comment: me arroja el mismo resultado si lo hago asi : select id, cost, siigoid,Descripcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que para tu caso serviría lo siguiente:

```
select
   colum1 as Total,
   colum2 as Co,
   CAST(Sum (price) AS float) as PrecioTotal,
   CAST(Sum(Amount) AS float) as TotalMes,
   CAST(Sum (NatAmount) AS float) as PrecioNal,
   (PrecioTotal + TotalMes + PrecioNal) as TotalCo
From
   Articulos,
   Tickets
Where
   fecha Between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
Group by
   Column1,
   Column2,
   Price,
   Amount,
   NatAmount
order by
   Total asc
```

Pruébalo y me cuentas. Ojo que cambié un alias por ahí.

Comment: gracias, tambien lo intente con una sola tabla asi: me arroja el mismo resultado si lo hago asi : select id, cost, siigoid,Descripcion   sum (cost) as Valor from articles where fecha between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'  group by id, siigoid,cost,Descripcion order by id, al parecer el formato de fechas estaba tomandolo inverso, ya lo rectifique pero ahora me sale "la conversion del tipo de datos char a datetime produjo un valor datetime fuera de intervalo"

Comment: gracias, persiste el error intentare cambiar los formatos de fechas

Comment: Veo que eso ya es otra cosa, aparte de lo de la suma. Te aconsejo hacer la siguiente prueba: Quita momentáneamente el where de la fecha y añade un limit 5 al final para que no te traiga tantos datos. Entonces prueba lo de la suma

Comment: Gracias, Cambie el formato de fecha ahora me sale error al convertir el tipo de datos varchar a float....

Comment: ¿Esos errores te los da el backend o estás directamente sobre sql?

Comment: estoy sobre el sql

Comment: Mira, prueba esto: A **todas** las sumas agrégale un  CAST de esta forma: CAST(Sum (price) AS float)  as PrecioTotal

Comment: Mil gracias, Ya me resulto¡

Comment: Excelente. Felicitaciones